# Android Error Failed to find target with hash string android-26 in Install missing platform(s) and sync project

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

When I try to install missing platforms it gets failed and I get this as an error:

```
Trying to install into C:\Users\anupam.garain\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-26\ but package "Android SDK Tools 26.0.1" already exists at C:\Users\anupam.garain\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\. It must be deleted or moved away before installing into a child directory.
Failed packages:
```

When I delete the folder and retry this, I get same error as android-26 folder is automatically created.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting Android Studio with administrative rights. Worked for me.